# Can you screenshot a Malicious website safely?

Tags: security, dns

I want to know if we try to screenshot a Malicious website through online tools such as url2png.com or geoscreenshot.com can still serve me infected websites java script and cookies etc?

Such websites can even screenshot landing page of the redirect/short URL's. 
During the redirect I'm assuming the DNS query isn't on my end either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two sites you mentioned are safe if you would like to screenshot a Malicious website.

Not all services will be safe, though. They browse (will take you) to the website from their own server and give back an `<img>` tag. Other sites might try to load the site in a `<iframe>` which may or may not be safe.